# Can you use an already created procedure and an already created function inside of a package?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL and I am trying to create a package that will contain and procedure and function that I have already created and stored into the database. Is there a way to simply use the already created procedure/function or will I simply need to recreate them inside of a package body?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/packages.htm#LNPLS00901

Comment: Sorry I was unable to locate a resolution to my problem after reading through this documentation.

Comment: You need to recreate the procedure and function in the package(Ideal case). -- OR -- Create procedure/Function inside the package and call already existing function/procedure from within to have same logic at only one place.

Comment: Ok I ended up recreating it inside of the package. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @G_Powersx08 you can call procedures and functions from other packages, e.g. `dbms_output.put_line('Hello');` Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, packages are used to provide modularity and ease of update to your work. That is why you have to create the procedures/functions inside the package.
However, this does not mean that you cannot call procedures/functions written outside. You have to create a proc/function and call the outside proc/function inside that, which increases your work.

So, it is always better to keep your work related to one module inside a package.
In short, create procedures/functions inside package.

Answer (score 1):

If the procedure/function is already created and deployed on database then you can use these in any Package you create on same schema, no need to recreate them inside you Package.
In case the procedure/function are created on schema different from your Package, all you have to do is to provide the execute privilege on the procedure/function to the schema where you are deploying your Package. Inside the Package just simply call the procedure/function by appending the owner schema in front (owner_schema.function_name(parameter)).

Hope this helps.